# Display popup only once per visit

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I want to show popup just once per session which expire after some time. Can someone help me?

```
function PopUp(){
    $('.home-popup').fadeIn(500);
}

setTimeout(function(){
  PopUp();
},1000); // 1000 to load it after 1 second from page load

$('.close-popup-btn').click(function() {
    $('.popup').fadeOut(300);
});
```

Comment: Are you looking to have the popup fade out automatically? In that case, you can also set a callback function on the fadeIn to occur when that has completed, to fade out after a given interval. If you're looking to make sure the popup doesn't continue to pop up during a given session, set a cookie.

Comment: @Snowmonkey I have close button for popup fadeOut, not closing automatically. How to set cookie, some example?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use localstorage for this as well.  To set a storage item: `localStorage.setItem('myPopup','true');` and to check for it you could do something like this:

```
var poppy = localStorage.getItem('myPopup');

if(!poppy){
    function PopUp(){
        $('.home-popup').fadeIn(500);
    }

    setTimeout(function(){
        PopUp();
    },1000); // 1000 to load it after 1 second from page load

    $('.close-popup-btn').click(function() {
        $('.popup').fadeOut(300);
    });
    localStorage.setItem('myPopup','true');
}
```

Comment: It does not have expiration.  But if you want it to clear out when the user closes the browser or tab, you could do:

`$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
  localStorage.removeItem('myPopup');
});`

Comment: I personally use this for an email collection popup in which I only want my users to see it once.  And not get bombarded with it and this works very nicely.  If a specific expiration date is necessary you will have to use a cookie.  LocalStorage is quick and easy.

Comment: Do you know or have some example how i can do this with cookie?

Comment: Are your pages PHP?

Comment: Actually refer to Antony's post below.  He has a pretty easy way of using Javascript to set cookies.

Answer (score 3):

I would set a cookie with the `popupSent` value on the first visit, and check if the cookie exists before calling the `PopUp` function.
Here is a rough implementation with the cookie helper functions from here:
[Set cookie and get cookie with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573223/set-cookie-and-get-cookie-with-javascript)

```
function PopUp(){
    $('.home-popup').fadeIn(500);
    createCookie('popup','1');
}
if(readCookie('popup')){
    // 1000 to load it after 1 second from page load
    setTimeout(PopUp,1000); 
}
$('.close-popup-btn').click(function() {
    $('.popup').fadeOut(300);
});
```